# Open Modal after click button refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In `Google chrome` works good, but when I click button in `Mozilla Firefox` open window on 1 second.

```
function openModal() {
  $("#openModal").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 450,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Close: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $("#openModal").hide();
      }
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
};
```

**Asp.Net:**

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClientClick=" return openModal();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work  me in `Google Chrome` and `Mozilla Firefox`, you can use that and I hope will help you :

```
$("#openModal").dialog({
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Close: function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
      //Reload the page
      location.reload(true);
    }
  }
});
```